# How is justifield Derek Parfit's Agony Argument in Subjectivism?

Tags: reference-request

Derek Parfit in his book climbing the mountain, does argues that moral subjectivism[1] does no survive what he calls The Agony Argument:

> Substantive subjective theories can have implausible implications. These theories
> imply, for example, that we often have no reason to want to avoid some future
> period of agony. Some Subjectivists would respond to this objection by appealing
> to claims about procedural rationality. This reply fails

As read adobe he says the following things:

1. That Substantive subjectivism does implies that we have no reasons to want to avoid a future period of agony.
2. Some Subjectivists would respond to this objection by appealing to claims about procedural rationality.
3. This reply fails.

Certainly I object do not agree with the First one, as follows:

Recall that [Reason](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/reason) means either (1.) "a statement or fact that explains why something is the way it is, why someone does, thinks, or says something, or why someone behaves a certain way" or (2.) "a fact, condition, or situation that makes it proper or appropriate to do something, feel something, etc." or (3.) " the power of the mind to think and understand in a logical way". or (4.) " ideas and opinions that are fair, sensible, and appropriate".

Recall that [Rational](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/rationality) means either (1.) "based on facts or reason and not on emotions or feelings" or (2.) "having the ability to reason or think about things clearly".

And certainly all Human action is rational (in sense 2), because all Human action is done because some one did used his cognitive abilities to determine that such action is required to fulfill a goal, in the case of ex post regret or incoherence with the goals is just because there were a mistake of calculus but nonetheless is rational; and no Human action in rational (in sense 1), because all Human goals are ruled by emotions, therefore no human action can be rational in the sense 2 because every action is bounded to the fulfillment of an emotion for more that have been used logic to conclude that the action must be done (Although arguments can be at least rational in sense 2 with respect to a commonly assumed axioms and premises). As would put Ludwig Von Mises:

> Human action is necessarily always rational. The term "rational action" is therefore pleonastic and must be rejected as such. When applied to the ultimate ends of action, the terms rational and irrational are inappropriate
> and meaningless. The ultimate end of action is always the satisfaction of some desires of the acting man. Since nobody is in a position to substitute his own value judgments for those of
> the acting individual, it is vain to pass judgment on other people's aims and volitions. No man is qualified to declare what would make another man happier or less discontented. The critic either tells us what he believes he would aim at if he were in the place of his fellow; or, in dictatoria1 arrogance blithely disposing of his fellow's will and aspirations, declares what condition of this other man would better
> suit himself, the critic.
> It is usual to call an action irrational if it aims, at the expense of "material" and tangible advantages, at the attainment of "ideal" or "higher" satisfactions. In this sense people say, for instance-some-times with approval, sometimes with disapproval (that a man who sacrifices life, health, or wealth to the attainment of "higher" goods) like fidelity to his religious, philosophical, and political convictions or the freedom and flowering of his nation-is motivated by irrational considerations. However, the striving after these higher ends is neither more nor less rational or irrational than that after other human ends. It is a mistake to assume that the desire to procure the bare necessities of life and health is more rational, natural, or justified than the striving after other goods or amenities. I t is true that the appetite for food and warmth is common to men and other mammals and that as a rule a man who lacks food and shelter concentrates his efforts upon the satisfaction of these urgent needs and does not care much for other things. The impulse to live, to preserve one's own life, and to take advantage of every opportunity of strengthening one's vital forces is a primal feature of life, present in every living being. However, to yield to this impulse is not-for man-an inevitable necessity. (Ludwig von Mises, Human Action, pages 18-19)

For such motives clearly I don't consider neither a valid critique nor a sound argument the point 1, because as follows the case that there can be reasons to want to avoid a future period of agony, in the senses 1 and 2 and even 4 (Note that the meanings 3 and 4 are mostly in consequential to the case), and because even if were no to want a future period of agony, then how exactly it means anything?.

Therefore the question is how Derek Parfit comes to this conclusions, and I would like some references about that?

[1]: I have no clear exactly to what he refers.

Comment: Parfit's argument is, essentially, that subjective morality is fleeting, this today, that tomorrow, so there is no reason to prevent future "harms" because they may well be embraced as blessings in that future. It is not very convincing, see e.g. [Sobel, Parfit’s Case against Subjectivism](https://academic.oup.com/book/3271/chapter-abstract/144267242):"*I maintain that subjectivists should embrace the thought that one necessarily has reason now to further the reasons one will have in the future. They can maintain that sound deliberation involves taking such future reasons into account.*"

Comment: @Conifold I find funny that people think that "Irrational Preferences/Desires" is a Thing. But Parfit's book is fill with no quite developed arguments and no references. I really need a better book of Taxonomy of the Ethical Theories.